# Exchange 2007 Receive E-Mail for other Domains

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007, windows-sbs

My organisation has Exchange 2007 e-mail server, and now, we want to host e-mail service for other organisation (neworg.com)
I added new Authoritative Active Domain neworg.com, but when adding a new mailbox, there is no option to chose new SMTP domain name neworg.com, and I can't add new user with SMTP domain user@neworg.com.

Probably I misunderstood something while reading posts on Internet, but can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add the new domain to your E-mail Address Policy, under Organization Configuration>Hub Transport>E-mail Address Policies.

Comment: So when I add new E-mail Address Policy, the final thing I need to do is to contact ISP of organisation which want E-mail service, for new MX record in DNS if I'm not wrong? Thx for answer!